# If $f_j\quad (j=1,2,\ldots)$ are analytic in a region $D$ and $\sum|f_j(z)|^2 $ is constant, then can we conclude that $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f_j\quad (j=1,2,\ldots)$ are analytic in a region $D$ and $\sum|f_j(z)|^2 $ is constant, then can we conclude that each $f_j$ is constant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each $f_j$ must be constant.

Here is a proof that works in a more general situation: consider a harmonic function $u = (u_1, \ldots u_N) \colon D \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^N$ ( smooth) with image inside a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$. Then  $u$ is constant. Use the mean value principle for harmonic functions. Consider $x_0$ in $D$. Take the tangent plane $\sum a_j y_j = b$ to the sphere at the point $(u_j(x_0))$. The function $\sum a_s u_j(x)- b$ has a maximum at $x_0$ and is harmonic so it must be constant.

In fact the set $u(D)$ has no extreme points unless $u$ is constant.